# Django form data not saving to database

Tags: django, django-database

I have a views.py that combined three forms from different models into one form on the template. The code seems to be operational and the print statements in the views.py doc suggest that the form is valid and all the relevant data is available. However, only data from `form1` and `form2` get saved to the database.

I've read (what feels like) dozens of threads on this website, but the print statements and purging the database were the last productive debug idea that I had and now I'm at a loss for how to debug this further. Pls come with the suggestions!

views.py

```
def consent(request):
    context = {
        'title': 'Consent',
    }
    print(Author)
    try:
        UD = UserDetails.objects.get(user_id=request.user.id)
        consent = UD.participate_consent
        if consent == True:
            username = request.user.username
            messages.warning(request, f'Hej, {username}, you already did that.')
            return redirect('profile')
    except:
        context['form1'] = None
        context['form2'] = None
        context['form3'] = None
        
        if request.method == 'POST':
            form1 = UserDetailsForm(request.POST)
            form2 = GetUserFirstLast(request.POST, instance=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id))
            form3 = GetAuthorInfo(request.POST, instance=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id))
            context['form1'] = form1
            context['form2'] = form2
            context['form3'] = form3
            if form1.is_valid() and form2.is_valid() and form3.is_valid():
                print(form1.cleaned_data)
                print(form2.cleaned_data)
                print(form3.cleaned_data)
                form1.save()
                form2.save()
                form3.save()
                username = form1.cleaned_data.get('username')
                messages.success(request, f'Thanks for consenting, {username}! \nNow we can get started.')
                return redirect('profile')
            else:
                print("a form is not valid")
        else:
            form1 = UserDetailsForm()
            form2 = GetUserFirstLast(instance=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id))
            form3 = GetAuthorInfo(instance=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id))
            context['form1'] = form1
            context['form2'] = form2
            context['form3'] = form3

    return render(request, 'users/consent.html', context)
```

Model related to form3

```
class Author(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.PROTECT, primary_key=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    slug = slug = models.SlugField(max_length=400, unique=True, blank=True)
    bio = HTMLField()
    points = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    profile_pic = ResizedImageField(size=[50, 80], quality=100, upload_to="static/users/authors/", default='static/users/authors/default.png')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.username

    @property
    def num_posts(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(user=self).count()
    

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.username)
        super(Author, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

forms.py related to form3

```
class  GetAuthorInfo(forms.ModelForm):
    user = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=True)
    profile_pic = forms.ImageField(label = profile_pic_label, required=False, initial='static/users/authors/default.png') 
    bio = forms.CharField(label = bio_label, widget=forms.Textarea())
    username = forms.CharField(widget=forms.HiddenInput(), required=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = ['user', 'profile_pic', 'bio', 'username']
```

EDIT start
Following (or trying) to follow advice in answers, form now looks like

```
class  GetAuthorInfo(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['points']

        labels = {
            'profile_pic': profile_pic_label,
            'bio': bio_label
        }

        widgets = {
            'bio': forms.Textarea(),
            'username': forms.HiddenInput()
        }
```

but still doesn't work.
EDIT end

relevant part of the template

```
            <form method="POST">
                {% csrf_token %}
                <fieldset class="form-group">
                    <legend class="border-bottom mb-4">{% translate 'Informed Consent' %}</legend>
                    {{ form2|crispy }}
                    {{ form1|crispy }}
                    <h4>For the forum</h4><hr>
                    <img src="{% static 'users/authors/default.png' %}" style="height:150px;width:200px;">
                    {{ form3|crispy }}
                    <input type="hidden" name="user" value="{{ user.id }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="username" value="{{ user.username }}">
                </fieldset>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <button class="btn btn-outline-info" type="submit">{% translate 'Submit' %}</button>
                </div>
                <div>{{ form.errors }}</div>
            </form>
```

Django version 3.2.5

Python version 3.8.10

OS Linux Mint 20.1

pls!

Answer (score 1):

the form has file fields so you to request file in views
like that

```
form3 = GetAuthorInfo(request.POST,request.FILES, instance=User.objects.get(id=request.user.id))
```

and in your html code

```
<form method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

please also change your form a bit

```
class  GetAuthorInfo(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['slug']
        # if you want to add widgets & labels to fields like
        labels = {
        'dob':'Date Of Birth',
        }
        widgets = {
        'dob': forms.DateInput(attrs={'type': 'date'})
        }
```

Comment: I took the request.FILES out and the profile_pic field out of models (and remigrated, etc) to see if that was the problem and forgot to put it back in for the question. Then there was no change – without the profile_pic field still nothing saved to the mode. Still, after following your suggestions, still no data saving to the database.

Comment: @Bob in  your forms.py why are u adding extra same field in form when you already crated that in models

Comment: Because that's how I learned –possibly wrongly– that you should indicate 'all' fields or just the ones you want. In this particular case, I don't want to populate `points` with this form (it's in the question because I didn't revert from my debugging), so the intention was to have all fields but points.

Comment: and you don have to add extra field  username when user is already connected with foreign key

Comment: @Bob try this  tell me if you still got error

Comment: I removed `slug` completely (it wasn't necessary).
```
class  GetAuthorInfo(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Author
        fields = '__all__'
        exclude = ['points']

        labels = {
            'profile_pic': profile_pic_label,
            'bio': bio_label
        }

        widgets = {
            'bio': forms.Textarea(),
            'username': forms.HiddenInput()
        }```

Comment: Not sure if I followed what you suggested the right way... still doesn't save to the DB. At some point my `form2 also stopped saving to the database. Print statements in views.py still show all correct data on submit.

Comment: update your code by edit in question section what you have done

Comment: done (thought the formatting would work in the comments)

Comment: seems that you are still requesting files

Answer (score 0):

fields = ['user', 'bio', 'username', 'profile_pic']

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but nothing changed.